# How can i save a list of images to a folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, list

I'm trying to save my list of images to a folder determined by the user, in this case I have this list.

```
List<System.Drawing.Image> ListOfSystemDrawingImage = new List<System.Drawing.Image>();

        ListOfSystemDrawingImage.Add(MatrizWPF.Properties.Resources.Earth);
        ListOfSystemDrawingImage.Add(MatrizWPF.Properties.Resources.Grass);
        ListOfSystemDrawingImage.Add(MatrizWPF.Properties.Resources.Rabbit);
        ListOfSystemDrawingImage.Add(MatrizWPF.Properties.Resources.Wolf);
```

Where Earth, Grass, Rabbit and Wolf are PNG images called the same way.

My question is, How can I store my

```
List<System.Drawing.Image> listOfSystemDrawingImage = new List<System.Drawing.Image>();
```

To a folder determined by the user?

Comment: How would you get the image names?

Comment: WPF with System.Drawing.Image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` for the user to pick the destination folder and use the `Image.Save` to save the image in the format of your chioce

Example:

```
List<System.Drawing.Image> listOfSystemDrawingImage = new List<System.Drawing.Image>();

System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var image in listOfSystemDrawingImage)
    {
        image.Save(string.Format("{0}\\Image{1}.png", dialog.SelectedPath, index), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        index++;
    }
}
```

**However, I do not recommend mixing Window.Forms and System.Drawing with WPF,**

Answer (score 0):

If you have the names you can just convert the image to a byte array and then use `File.WriteAllBytes`. Make sure the file name you pass toe `WriteAllBytes` has a .png extension. There's probably a simpler way but I don't really deal with media like that as much as raw data so this is what comes to mind for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the list of `System.Drawing.Image` this way:

```
string folder = @"C:\temp";
int count = 1;
foreach(Image image in listOfSystemDrawingImage)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(folder, String.Format("image{0}.png", count));
    image.Save(path);
    count++;
}
```

I don't know where you store the image names, so I just called them image1.png, image2.png, and so on.